# creating an index for percolate query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying percolate query in elasticsearch, but creating an index as explained in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) I'm greeted with an error. I ran the following:

```
PUT /my_percolate_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doctype": {
        "properties": {
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    },
    "queries": {
        "properties": {
            "query": {
                "type": "percolator"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm greeted with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
     {
       "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
       "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [my_percolate_index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [doctype, queries]"
     }
   ],
   "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
   "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [my_percolate_index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [doctype, queries]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: `ES 6.0.0-alpha1` and `NEST 6.0.0-alpha1`

Answer (score 1):

[Since you're using ES 6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-percolate-query.html), you just need to move the `query` field inside your mapping type

```
PUT /my_percolate_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "doctype": {
            "properties": {
                "message": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "query": {
                    "type": "percolator"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that as of ES 6, only a single mapping type is allowed within any index.

Comment: In my case i have `doctype` and `queries` as different types as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688396/852243) to be indexed to different indices.

Comment: Then you need to create two different indices, one with your message data and another with your queries.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seems like i'm succeeding in indexing the query property

Comment: I just spawned a new [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956630/nest-ignoring-my-percolate-query-property) as it's more on the `Nest` side of things.